# Proving a proposition is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to prove $P \lor ( Q$ XOR $R) \lor (R \rightarrow Q)$ is always true.

I got $P \lor ( R \rightarrow \lnot Q ) \lor (R \rightarrow Q)$.

Now I'm stuck at this part. I have no idea how to translate the "implies" into ANDS and ORS. My understanding is that for it to be always true, the proposition can be false or can be true like:

$(R \lor  \lnot R)$.

I was thinking maybe I can make it  $P \lor (R \land  \lnot Q) \lor (R \land Q)$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have see the notation $A \neq B$ for exclusive or.

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive or, sometimes denoted $\oplus$ or `XOR,` means "$A$ or $B$, but NOT both", and we define it as follows:

$$A \oplus B \equiv (A \land \lnot B) \lor (\lnot A \land B)$$

So you're expression is equivalent, to start, with:

$$P \lor (Q\oplus R) \lor (R\rightarrow Q) = P \lor (Q\land \lnot R) \lor \Big(\lnot Q \land R)\Big) \lor (R \rightarrow Q)\\ = P \lor (Q\land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot Q \land R) \lor (R\rightarrow Q)$$

You can "convert" from an implication: $A \rightarrow B$, by replacing it with its equivalent: $\lnot A \lor B$.

Be careful with parentheses!

Comment: From this P∨((Q∧¬R)∨(¬Q∧R))∨(R→Q) I get P∨((Q∧¬R)∨(¬Q∧R))∨(¬R V Q) but I don't know what to go from there onto proving its always correct. I tried doing it another way using ( Q ⊕ R) = (Q→¬R) so i would have P∨(Q→¬R)∨(R→Q). Then i changed the implications to ORs getting P∨(¬Q V ¬R)∨(¬R V Q). Then i regrouped it to P V (¬R V ¬ R) V (¬Q V Q). Since Q can be false or true that means its always true? I'm not really sure, or do I have to prove that P Q and R can be true or false? The thing with what you stated is that there is a bunch of ANDs and ORs but i not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @TuckerHughes $Q \oplus R \neq (Q \rightarrow \lnot R)$ when $Q=R=1$.

Comment: Your "other way" is not correct: $$Q\oplus R \not\equiv (Q\rightarrow \lnot R)$$

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I also have another question right now, If the proposition is ¬((A∧¬B)∨(¬A∧B)) V A V B, can I write it like this after distribution of the negation: (¬A V B) V A ∧ (A V ¬B) V B. If i'm able to do this then this would always be true correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a truth table like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
P & Q & R & Q \text{ xor } R & R \Rightarrow Q & (Q \text{ xor }  R)\lor (R \Rightarrow Q )\\ 
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
\end{align}
$$
(Here $1$ means true, and $0$ means false.) Since the lat column will be all $1$s, this proves that the statement is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I read your notation correctly, you have $((\lnot Q \land R)\lor (Q \land \lnot R) \lor ( R \to Q)$ above.

Using a truth table, show that $R \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot R \lor Q$, so the above becomes equivalent to $(\lnot Q \land R)\lor (Q \land \lnot R) \lor ( \lnot R \lor  Q)$.

Now note that $(Q \land \lnot R) \lor Q$ is equivalent to $Q$, and $Q \lor Q$ is equivalent to $Q$ (and similarly, $(Q \land \lnot R) \lor \lnot R$ is equivalent to $\lnot R$) hence the above is equivalent to
$(\lnot Q \land R)\lor \lnot R \lor  Q$.

Now note that $\lnot R$ is equivalent to $(\lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor \lnot R$,
and $(\lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot Q \land \lnot R) $ is equivalent to $\lnot Q$, hence the above reduces to $\lnot Q \lor \lnot R \lor  Q$.

Finally, we see that $Q \lor \lnot Q$ is always true, and hence so is
$\lnot Q \lor \lnot R \lor  Q$.

Comment: As an aside, when I was taught digital logic from an engineering perspective, we used $+,\cdot, \bar{ \cdot}$ for $\lor, \land, \lnot$ respectively, and I found (and still do) find these symbols much easier to work with.

Comment: Your missing a disjunct $P$ at the beginning

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, it was  deliberate omission, partly inspired by typing laziness.

Comment: Very well. ;-) Indeed, it's an unneeded appendage!

Answer (score 0):

"Implies" is translated like $A \implies B$ is the same as $(\neg A) \vee B$, check it with the truth tables.

Once you are done using de Morgan, distribution, and such, you'll probably have to do a tuth table.